# Spring-Boot 2.7 Redis PUB/SUB fails startup on missing Redis connection

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, publish-subscribe

I have this configuration for my pub/sub implementation:

```
@Bean
public RedisMessageListenerContainer container(LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                               MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {

    RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    container.addMessageListener(listenerAdapter, new ChannelTopic(publishChannel));
    return container;
}

@Bean
public MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(RedisReceiver receiver) {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
}

@Bean
public StringRedisTemplate template(LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return new StringRedisTemplate(connectionFactory);
}
```

This code worked fine until I updated to Spring-Boot 2.7 (previously 2.6.7).
Now this code throws the following error on startup, when my Redis is not running:

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean '**container**'; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost/:6379

("**container**" is the Bean at the top in my code snippet)

Where or how can I configure that it catches the thrown exception on startup and just retries it again until the connection to Redis is available?

UPDATE:

Did some digging and this part of the code is the culprit:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/blob/main/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/listener/RedisMessageListenerContainer.java#L1169

In comparison to the 2.6.x branch, where this was inside a try/catch (not sure though as it seems to be a completely different implementation), it is missing in version 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to wait for the next release, someone has fixed it and just [merged into maim](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/commit/14eebce19ccb08690f135dce87193f2e3771eaef)

Comment: Thanks for the info. My issue was closed with "works as intended". I hope this fix will make it to the end

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [PR](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/commit/14eebce19ccb08690f135dce87193f2e3771eaef) didn't fix the issue in the latest release (2.7.1), it really "works as intended" to Spring team :\

Here's my workaround:

`RedisMessageListenerContainer.Subscriber#initialize(...)` method is called when adding listener to the container, so what you need is to make sure the redis connection is available first, and then add the listener to container.

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MessageListenerSubscriber implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

  private RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
  private RedisMessageListenerContainer container;
  private MessageListener listener;
  private Collection<? extends Topic> topics;

  @Async
  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
    var template = new RetryTemplateBuilder()
      .maxAttempts(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
      .fixedBackoff(5000)
      .build();
    template.execute(context -> {
      try {
        var connection = connectionFactory.getConnection();
        if (connection.isSubscribed()) {
          log.debug("Retrieved connection is already subscribed; aborting listening");
          return null;
        }
      } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Connection failure occurred. Restarting subscription task after 5000 ms");
        throw e;
      }
      this.container.addMessageListener(listener, topics);
      log.debug("Listeners registered successfully after {} retries.", context.getRetryCount());
      return null;
    });
  }
}
```

and the configuration looks like:

```java
@Bean
public RedisMessageListenerContainer container(LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    return container;
}

@Bean
public MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(RedisReceiver receiver) {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
}

@Bean
public MessageListenerSubscriber messageListenerSubscriber(
    RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
    RedisMessageListenerContainer container,
    MessageListenerAdapter listener){
  return new MessageListenerSubscriber(
    connectionFactory,
    container,
    listener,
    List.of(new ChannelTopic(publishChannel))
  );
}
```